# How to use multiple simulator launches in Eclipse?

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a `MainThing.launch` starting the Simulator with `my.package.MainThing` as the argument. At first, I thought, I'd just copy and modify the Launch Configuration, but changing the program argument to `my.package.TheOtherThing` changed nothing. Still, the "MainThing" gets started.

So I thought, I could copy the launch file and change the line

```
<stringAttribute
  key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS"
  value="my.package.MainThing"/>
```

to contain `my.package.TheOtherThing` instead, but even after an Eclipse restart, nothing changes.

So what should I do in order to have multiple launches?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the simulator file multiple times, I'm guessing that what you are trying to do is run two separate main files. This is determined by the package and class name within `codenameone_settings.properties` which you need to change to run a different main class.

Comment: This is pretty uncomfortable and sounds like a bug: The argument to `Simulator` seems to be simply ignored, which is confusing.

Comment: Historically we used the argument then moved to use the content of the file. We never removed the argument from the newly created project. Using the settings file is better as it's more consistent across IDE's